# Retrieving 5 images using as many separate threads - jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following:

> Using an ajax call and json, retrieve 5 images using 5 separate threads. 
>   The results should populate the view as EACH of the image retrieval
>   calls returns.

All of this will be done locally and I was planning to use the jquery ajax method to retrieve these images from a json file.

I need to understand what it means by "using 5 separate threads" to retrieve these images.  How will that affect my ajax call?  What might the code look like?  Does a separate *thread* indicate a separate ajax call?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: sounds like a school question

Comment: How are you going to store the images in a json file? you probably meant file paths.

Comment: are you supposed to use Webworkers?

Comment: @KevinB: you are correct, I meant file paths.

Comment: @Evan: there is no requirement for that explicitly stated.  Do you believe that based upon the quote I provided webworkers are indicated?  Full disclosure: I've never used webworkers yet.

Comment: Generally you don't use ajax to retrieve an image an image, creating an image node and setting it's src value is enough. Ajax would only be good for retrieving the path to the image.

Comment: @KevinB: that indeed is my plan: get the file paths from the json files and and then set the image source.

Comment: *"using 5 separate threads"* is a very poor way of wording the problem. Since javascript is single-threaded other than the use of webworkers, it's all done on one thread anyway. Don't over-think it, just load the images. There's only one way to load an image, and that is to create an image, and set it's src to your image path (unless you consider using ajax to load the images data i guess.)

Comment: @KevinB: thanks for the efforts.  And I'll try not to think too much ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript in a browser environment does only support threading through WebWorkers, which themselves do not have access to the DOM-Tree.

All other kind of concurrency is "emulated" by an event based model. As launching an XMLHttpRequest from a WebWorker does not really make sense, all you can do is to make separate, *asynchronous* AJAX-calls and process the encoded image data in the corresponding event handler (yet encoding the image data in a JSON file does not make much sense to me, unless you have a very special application. But that's how I understood your question).

Edit:
A simple example of how to achieve this and considering that you only want to retrieve the image paths and assign those to image tags with the ids "img0"-"img4", you could write the following using jQuery:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    jQuery.ajax(
        {
            'async': true,
            'url': 'imagePath.json?idx=' + i,
            'context': {'idx': i}
        })
    .done(function (data) {
        $("#img" + this.idx).attr('src', data.path);
    });
}
```

Comment: so would you say that, based upon the quote I provided, the requirement for loading the images on "5 separate threads" doesn't really make sense?

Comment: Yes, as JavaScript _usually_ doesn't have threads, the task only makes sense if you read it as "Using an ajax call and json, retrieve 5 image paths using 5 separate asynchronous requests"

Comment: If you could, I would like to see an example, not a complete script but a basic structure of how 5 separate async requests might look using jquery ajax method.  My experience would be simply to make one ajax call, bring in all images and then expose them to the view.

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) jQuery.ajax({'async': true, 'url': 'imagePath.js?idx=' + i, context: {'idx': i}}).done(function (data) {$("#img" + this.idx).attr('src', data.path); });`

Comment: Note, `async: true` can be left off, that is its default value.